# Cassandra Plugin in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to make a plugin for Intellij for cassandra. After building the intellij community source code, I have managed to get into the development part. I have added cassandra driver via maven (**com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:3.0.0**). But when I deploy the plugin it gave me Linkage error(slf4j logger). So I excluded it from cassandra driver library. After that I am getting this exception while connecting to cassandra

```
ClassCastException: io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup cannot be cast to io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup cannot be cast to io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup
        at com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil.newEventLoopGroupInstance(NettyUtil.java:134)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.NettyOptions.eventLoopGroup(NettyOptions.java:96)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.<init>(Connection.java:706)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1365)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:162)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:333)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:283)
        at cassandra.NewMenu$1.actionPerformed(NewMenu.java:65)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.c(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

How to get rid of this exception? I have tried downgrading the cassandra driver version but no luck.

Comment: Any chance you open sourced this plugin? I'm trying to do the same thing and can't find any info on where to start

Comment: How far has this plugin got to? I would like to use it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have an issue with Netty version, try to use the **shaded** jar: http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/shaded_jar/

Comment: I dont't have any POM.xml. I am adding dependencies using project structure in intellij. how can i give the classifier attribute?

Comment: If you don't have a pom.xml then try to point to the shaded jar instead of the normal jar of the java driver